# Why "any covering of a compact set by a collection of open sets contains a finite subcovering"?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I'm reading Stein's textbook, and this is his version of the problem:

> A set $E$ is **bounded** if it is contained in some ball of finite radius. A bounded set is **compact** if it is also closed. Compact sets enjoy the Heine-Borel covering property:
>
> - Assume $E$ is compact, $E\subset\bigcup_\alpha\mathcal{O}_\alpha$, and each $\mathcal{O}_\alpha$ is open. Then there are finitely many of the open sets, $\mathcal{O}_{\alpha_1},\mathcal{O}_{\alpha_2},\ldots,\mathcal{O}_{\alpha_N}$ such that $E\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^N\mathcal{O}_{\alpha_j}$.
>
> In words, *any* covering of a compact set by a collection of open sets contains a *finite* subcovering.

I can't see how to prove it. Let's consider $\mathbb{R}$ and let $E$ be the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Are you considering subsets $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or just in $\mathbb{R}$? What work have you done to try to solve the problem so far?

Comment: It really depends on where you are starting from. Do you know that closed and bounded sets will be sequentially compact? (Meaning every sequence has a convergent subsequence).

Comment: Bit odd: every open covering having a finite subcover is usually the *definition* of a compact set. In some metric spaces, it's a stronger condition than being closed and bounded.

Comment: Two things are important to note: 1) your text is unusual in that the definition of compact is usually defined to mean every open cover has a finite subcover and you then prove that for $\mathbb R^n$ this is true if and only if it is closed and bounded. 2) there are spaces other then $\mathbb R^n$ where being closed and bounded does not mean every open cover has a finite subcover but (correct me if I'm wrong) if it is true every open cover has finite means closed and bounded.

Comment: Google Heine-Borel Theorem.  Bear in mind nearly everything you find will use "compact" to mean that every open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: *which* book by Stein?  Surely he offers a proof of this!

Comment: @fleablood.... To the proposer: As fleablood has noted, you have not stated which metric spaces this Q is about and which book this is from. If you edit the Q accordingly and include any details of your attempt you will get a  more supportive response.

Comment: The only way to answer his is to know the preceding material in that book.  Stein would not simply include this problem without considerable work leading up to it.  No student should be expected to prove this from scratch without that preceding work.  Or maybe Stein is stating this here, and will do the work of proving it later in the book.

Comment: You can easily find the PDF version of the book online, and you will see, he doesn't provide any proof, and the preceding material don't help much. He just sees it too obvious?! That annoyed me.

Comment: By the way this is not at all obvious and most importantly there does not seem to be any need of such theorem. My first encounter with it was regarding proof of uniform continuity. But later I found it to be equivalent to other forms of completeness principles and the result is useful in contexts where you need completeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of a classmate, I came up with a proof. Suppose U is an infinite collection of open intervals that covers [0,1]. Consider the following statement for the open interval I:

S(I): There exist a finite collection of open intervals in U that covers I.

We want to prove S([0,1]) is true.

Proof by contradiction:

S([0,1]) is false. Therefore, at least one of S([0,0.5]) or S([0.5,1]) is false. Continuing halving, we will converge to a point y for which S([y-e,y+e]) is false, no matter how small e is. However, there exists an open interval in U that covers y, and the length of this interval is greater than some e. Therefore S([y-e,y+e]) is true for some e. CONTRADICTION!

Please comment any mistake or sloppiness you observe.

Comment: Basically right. Details: Let $ I_1=[0,1].$ Assume $\neg S(I_1).$ If $S_n=[a,b]$  and $\neg S(I_n),$ let $I_{n+1}=[a, (a+b)/2]$  if $\neg S([a,(a+b)/2]),$ otherwise let $I_n=[(a+b)/2,b].$ By induction on $n\in \Bbb N$ we have,  for all $n\in \Bbb N,$   that $\neg S(I_n) $ and  $ |\min I_n-\min I_{n+1}|\leq 2^{n-1}.$ Now  $(\min I_n)_{n\in \Bbb n}$ is a Cauchy  sequence, so it  converges to some $x\in [0,1].$  If $U$ is $any$ open family with $\cup U\supset [0,1]$ there exists $e>0$ and $u\in U$ such that $[0,1]\cap (-e+x,e+x)\subset u$..... (continued)....

Comment: (Typo in prior comment: That should say $|\min I_n-\min I_{n+1}|\leq 2^{-n}$ ).... (continued)... Now $\max I_n-\min I_n=2^{-(n-1)}$ (also, obviously, by induction on $n$). So if $n$ is large enough that $|x-\min I_n|<e/2$ and $2^{-(n-1)}<e/2, $ then  $I_n\subset (-e+x,e+x)\subset u \in U,$ so $I_n$ is covered by the one member $u$ of $  U,$ contrary to $\neg S(I_n)$... I have assumed throughout that $\neg S(A)$ means that $A$ cannot be covered by a finite subset of $U.$ (Note that the $U$ of my comments is not the same as the $U$ of your answer, but is more general)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, would you like to post your solution as an answer? I prefer to select your proof as the accepted answer to the question.

Comment: I dk whether you can mark your own answer as Accepted but if  I suggest you do. I am a very slow typist so I would prefer not to re-type it. Thanks.

Comment: Another method: Let $C$ be an open cover of  $[0,1].$ For $x\in [0,1]$ let $x\in S$ iff $[0,x]$ can be covered by finitely many members of $C.$  Prove that (I) $S$ is not empty,  (II) $\sup S \in S,$ and (III) if $1\ne x\in S$ then $x\ne \sup S.$